# Use ViewModel in case other than Rotation

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

For what other purposes we can use [ViewModel](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi2w7_lhPPtAhW9zzgGHWdCA1EQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftopic%2Flibraries%2Farchitecture%2Fviewmodel&usg=AOvVaw3f_7HpGuQps9xX6BXFMqhB) for?

I have been asked if an *Activity* is locked to portrait mode, then is this relevant to use *ViewModel*?
If Yes why?

Comment: You can use it to share data between fragments in an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, *ViewModel* is an architectural component that "couples" a view with a model. From the architectural point of view it is relevant.

Additionally to the general component, Android Jetpack's *ViewModel* is also lifecycle-aware. You can treat it as a conveniency bonus.

With that being said, if the app is not supposed to have [configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ConfigurationChanges) (screen rotation is one of those) you may use any *CustomViewModel*.

Comment: What are the other configuration changes apart from Rotation?

Comment: [full list](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr?hl=ru#configChanges)